# Attempt to deference null object in Lightning calender

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have installed following package:

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000Ev8qpUAB

Requirement:

Here I'am trying to save "RelatedTOFied (Account)" of event Object, when  I passed that "Related toField" to sever then I got the error.

For ex:

```
     <aura:attribute name="acc" type="Account" default="0015B00000SSUQaQAP"/>
```

How I can set default value and make my code works?.If  passed "whatId field its throwing attempt to derefference null Object (please check my comments in code) and if I remove the code in "whatId: calender is working

code snipptes:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" controller="s360_AnyEventCalCtrl">
<ltng:require scripts="{!join(',', $Resource.AnyEventCal + '/moment.min.js', $Resource.AnyEventCal + '/moment-timezone.min.js', $Resource.AnyEventCal + '/jquery.min.js', $Resource.AnyEventCal + '/fullcalendar.min.js')}"
              afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}" />
<aura:attribute name="sObjectLabel" type="String" default="Event"/>
<aura:attribute name="sObjectName" type="String" default="Event"/>
<aura:attribute name="titleField" type="String" default="Subject"/>
<aura:attribute name="startDateTimeField" type="String" default="StartDateTime"/>
<aura:attribute name="endDateTimeField" type="String" default="EndDateTime"/>
<aura:attribute name="descriptionField" type="String" default="Description"/>
<aura:attribute name="userField" type="String" default="OwnerId"/>
<aura:attribute name="acc" type="string" default="0015B00000SSUQaQAP"/>
<aura:attribute name="filterByUserField" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
<aura:attribute name="eventsMap" type="Map"/>
<aura:attribute name="calendarButtons" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="weekends" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
<aura:attribute name="eventBackgroundColor" type="String" default="#CFEBFE"/>
<aura:attribute name="eventBorderColor" type="String" default="#ffffff"/>
<aura:attribute name="eventTextColor" type="String" default="#00396b"/>
<div class="slds">
 <div class="slds-card"> 
        <c:s360_EventCalendar objectLabel="{!v.sObjectLabel}"
                                   events="{!v.eventsMap}" 
                                   sObjectName="{!v.sObjectName}" 
                                   titleField="{!v.titleField}"
                                   startDateTimeField="{!v.startDateTimeField}"
                                   endDateTimeField="{!v.endDateTimeField}"
                                   descriptionField="{!v.descriptionField}"
                                   userField="{!v.userField}"
                                   calendarButtons="{!v.calendarButtons}"
                                   weekends="{!v.weekends}"
                                   eventBackgroundColor="{!v.eventBackgroundColor}"
                                   eventBorderColor="{!v.eventBorderColor}"
                                   eventTextColor="{!v.eventTextColor}"/>
   </div> 
</div>
```

---

```
({
 scriptsLoaded : function(component, event, helper) {
   helper.getEvents(component, event);
   }
 })
```

---

```
  ({
      getEvents : function(component, event) {

    var action = component.get("c.getEvents");
    action.setParams({ 
        sObjectName : component.get("v.sObjectName"),
        titleField : component.get("v.titleField"),
        startDateTimeField : component.get("v.startDateTimeField"),
        endDateTimeField : component.get("v.endDateTimeField"),
        descriptionField : component.get("v.descriptionField"),
        userField : component.get("v.userField"),
        filterByUserField : component.get("v.filterByUserField"),
        "whatId":component.get("v.acc")

    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
          //alert('event map values###'+JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
            component.set("v.eventsMap",response.getReturnValue());

        } 
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
} })
```

---

```
   @AuraEnabled
public static List<EventObj> getEvents(String sObjectName, String titleField, String startDateTimeField, String endDateTimeField, String descriptionField, String userField, Boolean filterByUserField,string whatId){

    String q = 'SELECT Id,' + 
        String.valueOf(titleField) + ',' + 
        String.valueOf(startDateTimeField) + ',' +
        String.valueOf(endDateTimeField) + ',' +
        String.valueOf(descriptionField) + ',' +
        String.valueOf(whatId) + ',' +
        String.valueOf(userField) + ' FROM ' + 
        String.valueOf(sObjectName) + ' WHERE ' + 
        String.valueOf(userField) + ' = \'' + UserInfo.getUserId() + '\'';
        if (!filterByUserField) {
        q = 'SELECT Id,' + 
            String.valueOf(titleField) + ',' + 
        String.valueOf(startDateTimeField) + ',' +
        String.valueOf(endDateTimeField) + ',' +
        String.valueOf(descriptionField) + ',' +
        String.valueOf(whatId) + ',' +
        String.valueOf(userField) + ' FROM ' + 
        String.valueOf(sObjectName);
    } 

    List<sObject> sObjectList = Database.query(q);
    system.debug('sobject list@@@@@'+sObjectList);
    List<EventObj> eventRecords = new List<EventObj>();
    if(isAccessible(sObjectName)) {
        for (sObject obj : sObjectList) {
            EventObj newEv = new EventObj(obj.Id,
                                          String.valueOf(obj.get(titleField)),
                                          DateTime.valueOf(obj.get(startDateTimeField)),
                                          DateTime.valueOf(obj.get(endDateTimeField)),
                                          String.valueOf(obj.get(descriptionField)),
                                          String.valueOf(obj.get(userField))

                                         );
            eventRecords.add(newEv);
        }
    }
    return eventRecords;
}
```

I recieved following error:
[image]

Comment: You do not need to apply `JSON.parse` to an attribute that is a simple constant. Also your posted .cmp is missing the attribute `con` that your JavaScript references making it hard to offer anything more. Also change the title if the question has changed.

Comment: I have already removed that code. while updating the question i didnt update it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attribute type is `Account` but you are passing `String`. SO you need to change it to `String` attribute type  to correctly hold the value.

```
<aura:attribute name="acc" type="String" default="0015B00000SSUQaQAP"/>
```

Comment: I did that change. I got this error.I have updated the question

Comment: @AnnappaPH As mentioned by KeithC you can try them.  Also instead of editing existing question it will be better if you post a new question with relevant detail and close this question.

Comment: Can you please close this post. I Will post questn with relvant details

Comment: @AnnappaPH once you accept any answer that post marked as closed.